# Catching runtime exceptions in IoC container

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net, caliburn

I'm using Spring.NET with Caliburn 2 and getting some exceptions from these frameworks at runtime (e.g. NoSuchObjectDefinitionException and UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Spring.NET, NullReferenceException in Caliburn).

These exceptions are being raised *after* my App.xaml.cs InitializeComponent() method has finished, meaning (as far as I am aware) there is no line in my code specifically causing the error, and therefore nothing to wrap in a try-catch.  Almost certainly I've misconfigured Spring or Caliburn somewhere, but I would really like whatever clues these exceptions contain in order to figure it out.

Is there some way to catch and inspect exceptions generated from third-party framework code at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can the use

```
Application.DispatcherUnhandledException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

events.

This should catch all exceptions you can't wrap with try/catch yourself.